# Alert Comes Continuously when clicks outside chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, onblur

I am using `onblur` on a text box and show an alert. But when I click outside my chrome browser after entering something in text box and then click on the chrome browser button in the task bar, the alert appears continuously. After clicking again on the chrome browser button the alert will appears only once.

This is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  Enter your name: <input type="text" id="fname" onblur="myFunction()">

  <p>When you leave the input field, a function is triggered which transforms the input text to upper case.</p>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementById("fname");
      alert(x.value.toUpperCase());
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try wrapping the alert in a `setTimeout(function() { ... your code ...}, 0);` - I've seen this with blur + chrome

Comment: That's because after you close the dialog (alert box), the focus returns on the `textbox`, therefore, the function will fire again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your question, I would recommend using `keyup` as shown below:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("fname");
  x.value = x.value.toUpperCase();
}
```

```html
Enter your name: <input type="text" id="fname" onKeyup="myFunction()">

<p>When you leave the input field, a function is triggered which transforms the input text to upper case.</p>
```